# Determinant of the matrix whose elements are given by a specific formula.

Tags: matrices

Calculate the determinant of $A_{n\times n}=((a_{ij})_{1\le i\le n})_{1\le j\le n}$ where

$$a_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j-1}$$

Comment: Thanks @DominicMichaelis for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: of course you mean for square matrices as DM notes. Hint, try a 2x2, 3x3 and look for a pattern to generalize.

Comment: Did you try anything? My first idea would be calculating for small $n$ and try to find a system

Comment: Yes i did try for small $n$ like $n=2,3,4$  but couldn't find any pattern in those determinants.

Answer (score 2):

This matrix is known as Hilbert Matrix, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: Thanks @pritam for the resource.

Comment: @Abhra Abir Kundu: You are welcome, once you know the formula you can try to prove it by induction.